# PyQT4 QWebView not resizing correctly

Tags: python, grid, resize, pyqt4, qwebview

I have a QWebview in a grid layout, along with other widgets. When the user resizes the window, the QWebview doesn't resize, but the other widgets do. How can I make the QWebview resize correctly?

Comment: The QWebView is included in the layout and handled by the layout manager?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're not using correct sizePolicy. Take a look here http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/layout.html

Does using other widget in place of QWebView change anything?

Answer (score 0):

in the dialog class's resizeEvent, one that extends QDialog, call webView->setGeometry, and this->resize, this->update.

hint: check if size changed via the QResizeEvent *ptr